# Navigate to existing instance of page in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, navigation

On a `Frame` in silverlight I want to be able to navigate to an existing instance of a `Page`. In short this is what I want:

```
Page p = ...; // initialize the page and set some of the properties
contentframe.Navigate(p);
```

Instead of using an Uri from which the page is created.

Can this be achieved (as in WPF), or should the frame rather be replaced by a `ContentControl`?

**Edit:** More clarity: Is there a way that `NavigationService.Navigate(object root)` that is available in WPF can be simulated in silverlight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question seems really quite confused.

> should the frame rather be replaced by a ContentControl?

That would imply that you don't have good reason to have the frame there in the first place and you aren't using a navigating framework.  In which case certainly you should replace the `Frame` with something else.

If you can replace the frame with something else the there is no need for your "Page" to be of type `Page`, it may as well be a `UserControl`.

It can all boil do down to have this simple Xaml:-

```
<Border x:Name="content" />
```

and this cs:-

```
UserControl p = ...; 
content.Child = p;
```

**Edit**:

You need to keep the frame therefore you can't replace it with a ContentControl.

You might just assign your `Page` directly to the `Frame` `Content` property.  However I'm not sure what would happen if you then click the back button.  I suspect it would navigate to the page prior to the page you replaced.

Another option would be to us a static service to push your page properties on to a stack, you page can then pop them off this stack when initialising.  This would allow you to navigate using a Uri to your page.

Comment: I would like to maintain the navigation if possible. In WPF you have a `NavigationService.Navigate(Object root)` method and a `NavigationService.Navigate(Uri uri)` method. In silverlight the first one is missing and whould like a work-around/alternative appoach for that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is the same problem that I am facing. An event happens outside the frame, and the page has no idea that the event has ocured, but it needs to be notified of that event.

Now what can be done is force the page within that frame to refresh itself or handle those events by 1: storing the page's state temporarily, and b) passing "commands" through the query string.